# CSS маска объектов

Tags: css

Доброго утра! Каким образом из верхнего блока с такой разметкой:

```
.header{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: #eeeeee;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #afafaf;
}
```

Сделать вот такой вот блок:

[image: Нужный результат]

Если можно какую нибудь интересную статью по этой теме, буду очень признателен.

Сейчас это выглядит так:

[image: Что, что ныне.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так:

```css
.header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #afafaf;
}
.header:before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -1px auto 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```